# How to specify weight and width for nested elements of GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` with two columns. I want to add fields to grid but don't know how to specify attributes for this.

**my layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context="com.mappolygon.PolygonDialogFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:columnCount="2">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_lat1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_lat1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/latitude_1"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_long1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_long1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/longitude_1"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_lat2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <EditText

                android:id="@+id/et_lat2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/latitude_2"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_long2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_long2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/longitude_2"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_lat3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_lat3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/latitude_3"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_long3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_long3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/longitude_3"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_lat4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_lat4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/latitude_4"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_long4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_long4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/longitude_4"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_coordinates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_build_polygon"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="@string/build_polygon" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My button handling( I'm using `Butterknife`)

```
   @Bind({R.id.et_lat1, R.id.et_long1, R.id.et_lat2, R.id.et_long2, R.id.et_lat3, R.id.et_long3, R.id.et_lat4, R.id.et_long4})
   List<EditText> coordinatesList;
   @Bind({R.id.layout_lat1, R.id.layout_long1, R.id.layout_lat2, R.id.layout_long2, R.id.layout_lat3, R.id.layout_long3, R.id.layout_lat4, R.id.layout_long4})
   List<TextInputLayout> inputLayoutList;
   @Bind(R.id.grid)
   GridLayout gridLayout;
**...**

   @OnClick(R.id.fab_add_coordinates)
   void addFields(){
        TextInputLayout inputLayoutLat = new TextInputLayout(getActivity());
        TextInputLayout inputLayoutLng = new TextInputLayout(getActivity());
        EditText editTextLat = new EditText(getActivity());
        EditText editTextLng = new EditText(getActivity());

        inputLayoutLat.addView(editTextLat);
        inputLayoutLng.addView(editTextLng);

        coordinatesList.add(editTextLat);
        coordinatesList.add(editTextLng);
        inputLayoutList.add(inputLayoutLat);
        inputLayoutList.add(inputLayoutLng);

        gridLayout.addView(inputLayoutLat);
        gridLayout.addView(inputLayoutLng);
    }
```

**So, How to set weight and width in this case?**

Comment: Use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager... GridView is no more a recommended approach.

Comment: I don't think weight was originally supported

Comment: @shivamDev I thought that it will be overhead for simple form. And can you share a link that GridLayout is deprecated?

Comment: @jak10h weight is supported in latest API's( I think from 21 or something). And if attribute `layout_columnWeight` exists and works, it should be way to set it via Java code

Answer (score 0):

`GridLayout` is especially good for putting views in a grid when you want certain views to span multiple rows/columns.  Usually in these cases you know which row/column a certain view needs to be in.

Looking more closely at your layout, I see you are editing latitude/longitude values, so you probably want two columns.  I'm guessing that you want to add rows programmatically in order to enable the user to enter an arbitrary number of coordinate pairs.

If this is the case, my suggestion would be to use a `ListView` for your views and add a new item to your list every time you need a new coordinate pair.  Your list item view could be a simple horizontal `LinearLayout`. Then you can achieve your goal of weighting the widths of the views while having arbitrary rows.

---

Yes, you can set the column weight in code by using the `GridLayout`'s `LayoutParams`.

```
     int row = ...;
     int col = ...;
     float rowWeight = ...;
     float colWeight = ...;
     GridLayout.Spec rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row, rowWeight);
     GridLayout.Spec colSpec = GridLayout.spec(col, colWeight);
     GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(rowSpec, colSpec);
     params.width = ...;
     params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
     inputLayoutLat.setLayoutParams(params);
```

As mentioned, this is only on API 21 and forward.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it explains what is Spec for me. But is there any way to add row without manual rows and columns check?